# Arduino Due: JTAG and SWD do not work after pressing erase button

Tags: arduino-due, uploading, programmer

I have an Arduino Due board. I can successfully upload code to it using Arduino upload via USB.
However I am also exploring another approach, which is to upload code via Atmel studio using an Atmel ICE and JTAG connection. Usually this works fine (the code uploads, and a simple "blink" sketch makes the onboard LED flash).

However when I press the erase button, and then try to upload the same sketch via Atmel Studio and JTAG, something strange happens. The code uploads fine:

```
Erasing device... OK 
Programming Flash...OK
Verifying Flash...OK
```

But then the program on the Due does not actually execute. The LED does not start to 'blink'. If I then again upload via USB (programming port) and the Arduino IDE, the blink program does work. And when I then upload via Atmel Studio and JTAG again without pressing the erase button, everything happens as expected too (LED blinks etc).
Does anyone have any idea what might be going on? The reason I ask is because I would like to design a board using only a JTAG connection. Do you think the above problem could cause issues when using a 'blank' factory SAM MCU as well?

EDIT: the same problem applies to SWD.

Blink sketch that i am uploading:

```
#define led LED_BUILTIN

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
  // initialize the digital pin as an output.
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(600);               // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(600);               // wait for a second
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After uploading via Microchip Studio, go to the GPNVM bits section of "device programming" window. Make sure boot mode is set to "boot from flash". Also check that GPNVMBITS register is set to 0x00000002. Then press "program". The sketch you uploaded to the MCU should now work.

So it seems what happens is that pressing the erase button resets the GPNVM bits so that the MCU boots from ROM, but then Atmel ICE + JTAG/SWD does not set the boot mode back to flash after (succesfully) programming the MCU.